# How to handle InputBinding Commands and ToggleButtons?

Tags: wpf, command, togglebutton, inputbinding

I have an InputBinding with the intention that F6 works as a shortcut to activate an edit mode, like this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="F6" Command="{Binding Path=ActivateEdit}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The button itself looks like this:

```
<ToggleButton Height="26" Width="26" Margin="0,0,1,1" Padding="1" 
                            ToolTip ="Bearbeiten (F6)" 
                            Command="{Binding ActivateEdit}"               
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsEditPressed, Converter={StaticResource boolToNullableBoolConverter}}"
                            IsTabStop="False" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Focusable="False">
    <Image Source="/Images/Edit.ico" Stretch="Fill" Height="16" Width="16"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

If the button is pressed manually the command is triggered. Also if the user presses F6. But in that case the button doesn't get the IsChecked state. How can I accomplish this without coding a different command for the KeyBinding?

Comment: Do you really need that converter for `IsChecked`?

Comment: Guess it's not really necessary in this case, yup. Probably I'm a victim of the fear of NULL syndrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your command "toggle" the `IsEditPressed` property, ideally this would be the only thing that needs to be done which makes it easier to keep everything in sync. You then would not even need the command on the `ToggleButton` itself as the `IsChecked` binding is enough.

Comment: Surely you would still need the Command binding on the ToggleButton to call the command when the button is clicked?

Comment: Indeed... There has to be a command on the ToggleButton, right? Otherwise: How would pressing the button execute that command?

Comment: Ah, I see now, H.B.!

I can put the code to actually execute the command in the Set part of the IsEditPressed and in the command itself simply switch the IsEditPressed to true or false. - Works great! Thanks for the tip!